# Drop a whole row of the dataframe if the text its not in English

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, textblob

I have a dataframe generated through an sql query.

The dataframe contains only text,description more specifically both in English and in German.

I want to drop the German descriptions or to create a new dataframe only with the English ones.

The descriptions vary from 150-1000 words.

I am using TextBloB module as it show bellow:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

test = reindexed_data.head()

for adv in test:

    x = TextBlob(adv)
    print(x.detect_language())
```

Where i get the desired values:

```
pl
de
en
de
de
```

I am pretty novice in the pandas framework and i am not sure how to drop the rows **or** create a new dataframe with the English only descriptions.

I also noticed that for 5 rows the TextBlop requires around 6 seconds,there are 5000 rows so if there is a different library or approach please suggest me.

To sum up:How can i drop rows that are on German and if there another library that can make the process faster?

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

**DataFrame Structure**

```
    0    zzCHzz
    1    Über Campusjäger GmbH Als Recruiter verbindet ...
    2    ALPADIA Language Schools is specialized in org...
    3    IT-KONTOR ist einer der führenden IT-Dienstlei...
    4    Kennziffer 59476PL       Unser Kunde ist ein d...

Name: JobAdd, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide an example of how is your dataframe structured?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i edit the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the index for those rows that are recognised as "en". Then use that index to select a subset of the dataframe:

```
test = reindexed_data.head()
indices = []
index = 0
for adv in test:
    x = TextBlob(adv)
    if (x.detect_language() == "en"):
        indices.append(index)
    index+=1

test_en = test.loc[indices]
```

Comment: Thank you!Worked :)